# Локальный DNS сервер

Tags: windows, веб-программирование, сервер, dns

Есть некоторое веб приложение, запущенное на виртуальной машине windows 7  которое должно работать в локальной сети. Сейчас для обращения к нему в браузере вбивается IP адрес сервера и порт. Есть ли статьи или материал, как настроить сервер, чтобы вместо IP адреса вводить какое либо выражение, по типу "www.mySite.rucom" (пока только начал изучать серьёзно сетевые технологии и понял только, что надо создавать локальный DNS сервер) ?

Comment: Сначала хотел предложить `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, но потом перечитал вопрос.

Comment: Использовать любой роутер, который поддерживает локальный DNS. Например, это точно умеет микротик или openwrt